# Chrome - All pages blank

Tags: google-chrome

My Chrome browser stopped working yesterday without any good reason. It shows all pages blank, even bookmarks, settings etc. I don't have access to anything. Did anyone experienced this type of problem with Chrome browser?

This is how it looks:

[image: Crome blank pages]

I have 64-bit Windows 7. I tried to restart PC, reinstall browser but without success. I didn't install any new programs in last two days. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This sort of question is not suitable for StackOverflow forum. I would rather suggest you try some other forum and refer the StackOverflow FAQ section for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday, and I have the same setup as you do. If you try minimizing and maximizing the window, every once and a while it will fix it right? I updated the browser and the issue seemed to disappear.

I also use a program called Dexpot for virtual desktops similar to what you get in Ubuntu, and I found that after switching desktops a lot I would get this issue.

I solved the issue by simply updating chrome. Obviously, this didn't solve your issue. I would recommend you make sure you aren't running in 32 bit compatibility mode, or some other compatibility mode.